# AttributeError: generator object has no attribute 'sort'

Tags: python, sorting, iterator, generator

I have two files .. I use round robin to read a line from the first file and the second line from the second file.

```
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).next for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))
```

Then:

```
c= roundrobin(a, b)
```

a and b are list. How it can be round robin with sorting?.. I tried to use

```
c.sort()
```

But the error is

> AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'sort'

I need to sort c based on the elements of the first column (d/M/Y)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error indicates, generators do not have a `sort` method. You can instead exhaust a generator via built-in [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), which accepts an *iterable* as an input. Here's a trivial example:

```
def randoms(n):
    import random
    for _ in range(n):
        yield random.randint(0, 10)

res = sorted(randoms(10))  # [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 10]
res = randoms(10).sort()   # AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'sort'
```